# Having issues adding a new web page in Django

Tags: python, html, django

I am new here. I have googled for help regarding my issue to no avail. I am new to Python and the Django framework.

Issue I am facing:

I have a website built with the Django framework. In this website, I have a drop-down menu and I want to add a new page there. This new webpage only contains text and there is no user interaction needed.

1) I have created the new webpage, and put it in the "webapps/template" folder.

2) I updated the urls.py file with the new webpage's url in the "webapps" folder.

3) I have updated the base.html with the new webpage's url in the "webapps/template" folder.

I have worked with 3 files in total: new webpage, urls.py and base.html.
When I upload the files, the site breaks. What am I missing here?
Do I need to update another URL file somewhere? Please advise?

Comment: You are going to need to provide more information: please share your project structure, `urls.py` file, `views.py` file, `settings.py` file and `base.html` file.

Comment: "When I upload the files, the site breaks". What does this mean? How are you "uploading" the files? Does it work locally in development? What errors do you get in production when it "breaks"?

Comment: We need an error message or some of the files used

Comment: Hi guys, thank you so much for offering to help out. I have figured out the issue; all I had to do was restart the web server after making the changes. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue; all I had to do was restart the web server after making the changes. Thanks anyway guys!

Comment: this should be only in comment.